# How to associate more than one file extension types to my iPhone App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

How to associate more than one file extension types to my iPhone App  already i have included the bundle extension but now i want to add facility to include files with extension .csv

I am refering to below  [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1980/how-to-import-and-export-app-data-via-email-in-your-ios-app) to associate file extension to my iPhone App

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create more than two items inside the `CFBundleDocumentTypes` entry, which is an array.

In general, before googling for a blog article and/or asking questions at StackOverflow, **go to developer.apple.com and read the relevant documents**. In this case, read [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010411-SW1).